Identify a cartoon movie about an artist sleeping under a magic tree and becoming able to talk with animals
I think this movie is an american film from the 80s. The main character was an artist that went into a forest and fell asleep under a magic tree. When he woke up, he was able to talk with the forest's animals.
In the forest, the animals had problems with the main villain, a cactus-like creature (I can't remember his motivations), the solution of the conflict involved a prophecy that mentioned a future with flowers.
During the events of the movie, the artist was captured by mushrooms (I can't remember how he managed to scape).
The end of the movie happens when the cactus villain flowers and turns good. Then the spell on the artist (given by the magic tree) dissapears, he cannot understand and talk with animals anymore, says good bye and returns home.
Other thinks I can remember:

One of the lead animal characters was a fox
One of the mushrooms that captured the artist imitated a rock singer (I think it was Michael Jackson).
While the artist is captured by the mushrooms, they sang a song.

Edit: After I got the answer by @Walt, I knew this movie was from Yugoslavia. It was aired in Perú (dubbed to Latin American spanish) in late 80s.

Sounds like The Elm-Chanted Forest from 1986.

A painter falls asleep beneath a magical elm tree and awakens with magical powers that allow him to communicate with the creatures of the forest. In the limited time that he possesses these powers, he must help save the forest from the threat of the evil Cactus King.

Followed by a sequel in 1990. Here's the trailer:




Yees, it is this one! :D
